# How to "properly" display a 2d sprites in a 3d environment?

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d, sprites

I would like to show "the classic" missile lock viewfinder (the target symbol) of a war aircraft. 
So the target symbol must follow the enemy, and became red when "lock" it. 
So i thought simply to Show the 2d sprite centered on screen (x and y = screen.height and width /2 )  but, depending of the Z , the sprite became bigger (near camera) or smaller (far from the camera).

How to display a 2d sprite indipendent from Z axis ?

Thanks

Comment: Search for orthogonal projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to place the 2d sprite not in the game world but instead place it on a [UI canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html) with "Screen Space - Overlay" mode.

You can convert the game-world position of a GameObject to screen-coordinates using `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`. Then you need to convert the screen coordinates to canvas coordinates and place your sprite there.

Code stolen [from answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/799616/unity-46-beta-19-how-to-convert-from-world-space-t.html):

```
var viewport_position = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(world_position);
var canvas_rect = canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

var sprite_position = new Vector2(
    (viewport_position.x * canvas_rect.sizeDelta.x) - (canvas_rect.sizeDelta.x * 0.5f),
    (viewport_position.y * canvas_rect.sizeDelta.y) - (canvas_rect.sizeDelta.y * 0.5f));
```